# Multiply two Pandas dataframes with same shape and same columns names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes A, B with NxM shape. I want to multiply both such that each element of A is multiplied with respective element of B.

```
e.g:
A,B = input dataframes
C = final dataframe
I want C[i][j] = A[i][j]*B[i][j] for i=1..N and j=1..M
```

I searched but couldn't get exactly the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I  think you can use:

```
C = A * B
```

Next solution is with [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
C = A.mul(B)
```

Sample:

```
print A
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  7

print B
   a  b
0  2  3
1  1  4
2  3  2

print A * B
   a   b
0  2   9
1  2  16
2  9  14

print A.mul(B)
   a   b
0  2   9
1  2  16
2  9  14
```

**Timings** with lenght of `A` and `B` **300k**:

```
In [218]: %timeit A * B
The slowest run took 4.27 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.57 ms per loop

In [219]: %timeit A.mul(B)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.56 ms per loop

A = pd.concat([A]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)
B = pd.concat([B]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

print A * B
print A.mul(B)
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael! I should have tried this before asking.

Comment: No problem, I was not sure too, but rather I write answer and then verify it by sample.

Comment: I add timings, please dont forget accept,upvote answer. Thanks.